# How to convert a UTC String to a Formatted Date in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, date, utc

I have a UTC Date as follows:
Mon Aug 30 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

Is there any jQuery or JavaScript function that converts the UTC date string to mm/dd/yyyy format?

I searched high and low and cannot find anything. Thanks!

Comment: You mean [DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat)? That's almost literally the first example =) (also note that for custom schemes, the [.format()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/format) function's got you covered)

Comment: you need somthing like ``` new Date("Mon Aug 30 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0400").toLocaleDateString()```  checkout https://css-tricks.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-date-in-javascript/

Comment: Thanks @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans -- that answered the question!!

Comment: Moufeed, Solomon: remember not to put code answers (even if they're questionable answers) in comments. Write an answer, and explain why you gave that specific code.

Comment: I've vote to close this one (if you don't delete it first =) as it's already covered by the standard JS docs for working with dates.

Comment: I put it as an answer

Comment: "Mon Aug 30 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)" is not a "UTC Date" in any respect, it's a timestamp in the format produced by [*Date.prototype.toString*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.tostring). UTC is a time standard that does not specify formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Date.parse  and Intl.datetimeformat as in

```js
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(Date.parse("Mon Aug 30 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)")));
```

Comment: You really shouldn't answer questions that have been asked many, many times before (there are over 130 answers across the marked duplicates that the OP can learn from). Mark them as duplicates. If the OP has trouble applying the duplicate to their question, they can ask another question with what they're having trouble with.